# Suppose z=(3+ai)/(6+bi) for some constant a and b . If Re(z)=1 and Im(z)=5 , find a and b .

Tags: complex-numbers

I've tried several ways but still don't know how to solve this...
Could anyone help me?

$z=(3+ai)/(6+bi)=(3+ai)(6-bi)/(6+bi)(6-bi)=(18+a+b+6ai-3bi)/(36+b^2)$
$1=(18+a+b)/(36+b^2)$
$5=(6a-3b)/(36+b^2)$
and I stucked here...

Comment: Hint: 6-bi, numerator, denominator.

Comment: Welcome here! Can you give details about these "several ways"? Maybe one of these failed attempts can be fixed, or pushed to their conclusion to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by conjugate to get rid of denominator

$$z=\frac{3+ai}{6+bi}=\frac{(3+ai)(6-bi)}{36+b^2}=\frac{ab+18+i(6a-3b)}{36+b^2}$$

Then: $$\frac{ab+18}{36+b^2}=1, \frac{6a-3b}{36+b^2}=5$$

Solve this system of equation:

$ab+18=b^2+36$, $6a-3b=5(ab+18)$ so $a=\frac{3b+90}{6-5b}$

Then:$$b.\frac{3b+90}{6-5b}+18=b^2+36$$ give $b=\frac{3}{5}$ and $a=\frac{153}{5}$

EDIT: use Gerry Myerson's comment:
$(1+5i)(6+bi)=(3+ai)$ i.e: $6-5b+i(30+b)=3+ai$ which implies: $6-5b=3, 30+b=a$ then $b=\frac{3}{5},a=\frac{153}{5}$

Comment: Easier: $(1+5i)(6+bi)=3+ai$ gives two linear equations in the two unknowns.

Comment: Ah, i totally forgot this, shame. Thank you for your precious comment.